# Display vs Edit Mode in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating an MVC 5 web project that collects numerical data from the user.  The majority of the fields are nullable decimals and I have a requirement to display them to various decimal places while maintaining the full precision when writing back to the database.

The view model has properties such as:

```
public decimal? TonnesOfFoo { get; set; }
public decimal? TonnesOfBar { get; set; }
```

The view itself renders the controls as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TonnesOfFoo, "{0:N1}", new { @class = "form-control" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TonnesOfBar, "{0:N3}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This works well and presents the data as needed however when the form is posted back I am writing the rounded values back to the database.

Is there any way around this without having "actual" and "display" properties in my view model and using jQuery to sync them all up?  Is there some kind of editor template I could use to handle this situation?

**UPDATE**

Using the suggestion from M.Ob I have finally managed to get this working.

I am no longer using the in-line formatting, instead I am using two data attributes, one for the full precision and one for the number of decimal places required.  For example
:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TonnesOfFoo, new { @class = "form-control", data_fullprecision = Model.TonnesOfFoo, data_precision = 1 })
```

Then on document ready I loop through and manually apply the formatting using the [jQuery Number Plugin](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178):

```
$('input[data-fullprecision]').each(function () {
     var selector = '#' + this.id;
     var precision = parseInt($(selector).data('precision'));
     var fullprecisionValue = $(selector).data('fullprecision');

     if ($.isNumeric(fullprecisionValue)) {
          var roundedValue = $.number(fullprecisionValue, precision, '.', '');
          $(selector).val(roundedValue);
     }
});
```

I am not sure if the above is overkill but I needed a way to present the data in the correct format if any validation errors occurred in the controller, without this the un-rounded values were displayed along with the validation messages.

I use a similar scripts to map the values to the data attributes when the user changes a value and finally to map the full precision numbers to the text boxes before the form is submitted.

Comment: What happens when the user types 1.01 in your first example? Will it round to 1.0? Or does it save 1.01 to the database?

Comment: By display to various decimals, do you mean in a separate read only view or are you expecting to have inputs also display to only the same number of decimals?

Comment: Patrick - it would post back 1.01 but I would loose the rounding on any items the user didn't edit

Comment: Stephen - I would like to use one textbox per item.  Ideally the number would be rounded until the user clicked into it then the full value could be shown

Comment: "the number would be rounded until the user clicks"? How do you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way, but here is one idea:

You could do something like this: store your full precision value in a data- attribute of your textbox.  Then, when the user changes the text, us JS to update the data- attribute to the new value.  Upon form post, you can then have a JS function update your text boxes' values with the data- values before the submit occurs.  This way, all of your new(updated) values and your untouched textbox values will be properly posted over not rounded.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TonnesOfFoo, "{0:N1}", new { @class = "form-control", data_fullprecision = Model.TonnesOfFoo })
```

Comment: I was trying something similar to this while I was waiting for a response but I would then need to map everything back if any validation errors occurred upon post.  I am now thinking it may be easier to keep a list of "changed" fields and manually map everything back to the model rather than using automapper...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "need to map everything back".  Do you mean back to the original values or to the values the user entered?
Wouldn't you just post, validate, and if not valid, return the view with the posted model?  This way you can show the validation errors and still have the values the user entered so they know where they went wrong.  Not sure where automapper comes into this.

Comment: Maybe you use Hidden Fields to store the precise values?

Comment: M.Ob - if I submit the data and decide that the ModelState is not valid the full precision values are still shown in the text boxes.  I am not sure how to force the values to be rounded again when the validation messages are displayed to the user.

Comment: Are you wiping out their incorrect values when you are showing the error messages to the user or do you just want to round their incorrect values?  If you want to wipe out their stuff, just re-build your model and return the view with that model (which would contain the original values).  If you want to keep their values, but just have them rounded, you should be able to return the view with the updated model (with their data) and the formatting on the textboxfor will format the data.  If is is not for some reason, you can always clear the modelstate before adding your errors to the modelstate

Answer (score 0):

I would use a view model that contains the original values and the rounded displayed values, when persisting back to the DB, compare the original values with the rounded values, if a value hasn't changed persist the original value, if it has persist the new value.

I'm of the opinion this would be the easiest solution to this problem, although performance might not be the best.

Other solutions might be to look at using Knockout on the client, and tracking which values have changed, and then only saving those values